# responsive product display

Tags: css, responsive-design

My problem webpage: http://doubleknityarn.com.hk/home-shop-style-3/

For a mobile device (e.g. Samgsung S4), I would like to arrange 2 products per row, instead of 1 product per row, in a mobile responsive design.
I have created a child theme, but I cannot figure out what's wrong with my codex that I cannot make it 2 products per row.

Below are my CSS code for my child style.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 651px) { 
    .woocommerce ul.products li.product,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product{ 
        clear: both; 
        float:left; 
        margin:0 0 1em 0; 
        padding:0; 
        position:left; 
        width:46%; 
        margin-left:-20;
    } 
}
```

Anyone can help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your correct code should be like this

```
@media (max-width:651px) {

ul.products li.product {
width: 45%;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;
}


.products li, #main .products li:nth-child(3n),
#main .products li:nth-child(4n) {
float: left!important;
margin-left: 10px !important;
margin-right: 10px !important;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have input your code, but still I cannot make it 2 products per row.....

Comment: Your product grid still has css that sets it to float: none !important.
This makes it so that your only going to get one product item per line. Your product grid css isn't very clean and uses a lot of !important's, overriding it will be fun.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier, your website theme is using very dirty css and you must solve it soon. At present, you can follow my these suggestions.

Download your this file `wp-content/avada/css/media.css` first and copy-paste all the codes I've made in this [link](http://pastebin.com/su7Frr75) into media.css and update.

Answer (score 0):

although I have solve the small screen problem, I found another problem:

I found my iPad vertical (768 X 0124) was now not responsive on the same page:
http://doubleknityarn.com.hk/home-shop-style-3/

Any advice here?